# Elastic bean stalk upload new version error(AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dropwizard

I am facing an error with AWS EBS which is uploding a new version into ebs through console.It is working fine for somedays but suddenly it is not working when uploding a new version.I searched on google but no use(i didnt get any relevant answer).Can any one suggest me why this error was occurred and how to solve this .Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

These may be reasons:
1. The size of the application version (.war or .zip file) exceeds 512 MB. You must reduce the size of your application source bundle if you want to upload it to your application. 
2. Your environment has reached the maximum number of application versions. Delete unneeded versions or request a limit increase.

Comment: My zip file size is 40 MB.can you please tell me how many versions per instance(free)?even i deleted all my versions i.e., no zip files are there  ,showing same problem